# Reverse proxy vs redirect vs fetch url

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, image

I have two servers (both publicly accessible). The first is the image storage server. The second generates links (small script written in node.js) that will point to images on the image storage server.

I have a front-end web page that will need to load photos from the image storage server. In order to do so it will need to contact the "link generation" server in order to get the link.

There are 3 ways I am thinking of doing this:

1. Store the image ID data in a `data-src` tag as part of the `<img>` rather than the `src` tag so the browser doesn't attempt to load it as an image. Then let some javascript function ping the link generation server with the image ID, retrieve the actual image link and then place that in the `src` tag.
2. Make the link generation server redirect to the appropriate image link instead of returning the link as text so a link to the image generation server with the image ID can be placed in the `src` tag and the browser will resolve the image through the redirect. (I'm assuming that images can be resolved through a redirect?)
3. Make the link generation server into a reverse proxy that will load the resulting image itself and then pass the image back instead of returning the link as text. Similarly the link to the image generation server with the image ID will be placed in the `src` tag and no special javascript is required to resolve the image.

---

**My question is:** Are any one of these more desirable than the other in terms of image loading speed and "cache-ability"? So far I see the redirect method being the more desirable as it's clean and doesn't require any special javascript. But with such a method (if it even works) would the final image not be able to be cached in the browser for subsequent re-loading of the page because the browser will always be resolving a redirect to actually get the final image link?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you presumably have control over both the image server and the link generator, I would suggest combining them into a single web service.  Essentially, like option #3, whether by using a reverse proxy, or by combining the two server apps into a single app, which would be potentially more performant (one fewer HTTP request per image load).  This is a more elegant solution, in my opinion, creating a single, simple image web service without involving redirects and multiple HTTP requests in the client/browser.

Regarding images src URLs, yes, they can be resolved through redirects, and the image of redirect URL will be cached by the browser if the caching headers are correct.  301 redirects are cacheable, as well, with the correct caching headers.  Again, this approach seems more convoluted as a service, but business costs may dictate in the end.

In summary, I'd stay away from #1 all together, as it puts the burden of using the image service correctly on the client.  Whether you go with #2 or #3, should probably depend on the immediate development costs and long term maintenance costs of choosing one over the other.

Comment: Interesting - the image storage service is written in python and the link generator service is in node.js. I think I will want to keep them separate. Why would there be a performance benefit when using a reverse proxy as opposed to a redirect? At the end of the day, 2 http requests are being made either way. Either one by client and one by link generator server (reverse proxy) or both by the client (for a redirect).

Comment: You are correct.  I was referring to combining the two image apps into a single app, instead of using a reverse proxy.  I understand you're wanting to keep them separate, now.  Something to consider about performance, regardless, is that browser-server HTTP requests are typically slower than server-server HTTP requests.  The reason being browsers typically have slower network connections, while servers typically have faster connections, especially if they're hosted in the same data center.